# Equality of Supremum

Tags: real-analysis

There are many proofs on this site showing that for bounded sequences ${a_n}$ and ${b_n}$ that the inequality $sup\{a_n +b_n\} \le sup\{a_n\} + sup\{b_n\}$.

Is there any way to prove we have equality using the definition of supremum that if ${a_n}$ is equal to a constant $a$ for all terms in the sequence, then equality holds. In other words can we rewrite the above inequality in this case as $sup\{a_n +b_n\} = a + sup\{b_n\} = sup\{a_n\} + sup\{b_n\}$ in such a case. I can't think of a counterexample but can't figure out how to directly prove it from the definition of supremum.

Comment: Perhaps that you meant $\sup(a+b_n)=a+\sup b_n$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos sorry, I updated the question to make it a little clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Assume $a_n=a, \forall n.$ Now, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $n$ such that $b_n>\sup b_n-\epsilon.$ So

$$a_n+b_n=a+b_n>a+\sup b_n -\epsilon.$$